# Copy values from XML element to create a new element with combined new value

Tags: javascript, python, php, bash, command-line

I have this XML with multiple products and I want to add a new element with the values of other elements. I want to add a new element to each  titled . This should include the values of ProductOption, PurchaseOption, Quantity. Example should look like `<sku>price-each-an-order-250-499</sku>`.
I am open to different technologies, like command line sed, bash etc.., php, python, javascript.

Input XML

```
<Catalog>
    <Product>
        <Number>82508</Number>
        <Title>Product Title</Title>
        <Description>description</Description>
        <Variations>
            <!-- An Order; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>250-499</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>250</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>499</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>1.09</Price>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>500-999</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>500</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>999</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.95</Price>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>1000-2499</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>1000</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>2499</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.93</Price>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>2500-4999</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>2500</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>4999</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.87</Price>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>5000</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>5000</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity></MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.84</Price>
            </Variation>
            <!-- A Quote; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>A Quote</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity></Quantity>
                <MinQuantity></MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity></MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.00</Price>
            </Variation>
            <!-- A Sample; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>A Sample</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>1</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>1</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.00</Price>
            </Variation>
        </Variations>
    </Product>
</Catalog>
```

Expected Output

```
<Catalog>
    <Product>
        <Number>82508</Number>
        <Title>Product Title</Title>
        <Description>description</Description>
        <Variations>
            <!-- An Order; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>250-499</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>250</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>499</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>1.09</Price>
                <Sku>price-each-an-order-250-499</sku>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>500-999</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>500</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>999</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.95</Price>
                <Sku>price-each-an-order-500-999</sku>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>1000-2499</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>1000</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>2499</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.93</Price>
                <Sku>price-each-an-order-1000-2499</sku>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>2500-4999</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>2500</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>4999</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.87</Price>
                <Sku>price-each-an-order-2500-4999</sku>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>5000</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>5000</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity></MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.84</Price>
                <Sku>price-each-an-order-5000</sku>
            </Variation>
            <!-- A Quote; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>A Quote</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity></Quantity>
                <MinQuantity></MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity></MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.00</Price>
                <Sku>price-each-a-quote</sku>
            </Variation>
            <!-- A Sample; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>A Sample</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>1</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>1</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.00</Price>
                <Sku>price-each-a-sample-1</sku>
            </Variation>
        </Variations>
    </Product>
</Catalog>
```

Not sure what to use to accomplish this. Any examples or tutorials would be helpful.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is generally frowned upon for this site, as well as just listing a bunch of languages and hoping someone will write this for you. Instead we'd ask you to try something, preferably in a language you are comfortable with, and once you get stuck post a question here.

Comment: If you really don't know where to start, this is honestly a great use-case to give some of the AI programs a shot. From your question, provide sample XML inputs and outputs, and tell them your language. They should be able to give you some sample code that might be fairly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution with python `xml.etree.ELementTree`. You find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """
<Catalog>
    <Product>
        <Number>82508</Number>
        <Title>Product Title</Title>
        <Description>description</Description>
        <Variations>
            <!-- An Order; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>250-499</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>250</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>499</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>1.09</Price>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>500-999</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>500</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>999</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.95</Price>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>1000-2499</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>1000</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>2499</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.93</Price>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>2500-4999</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>2500</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>4999</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.87</Price>
            </Variation>
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>An Order</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>5000</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>5000</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity></MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.84</Price>
            </Variation>
            <!-- A Quote; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>A Quote</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity></Quantity>
                <MinQuantity></MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity></MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.00</Price>
            </Variation>
            <!-- A Sample; no imprint -->
            <Variation>
                <ProductOption>Price Each</ProductOption>
                <PurchaseOption>A Sample</PurchaseOption>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <MinQuantity>1</MinQuantity>
                <MaxQuantity>1</MaxQuantity>
                <Price>0.00</Price>
            </Variation>
        </Variations>
    </Product>
</Catalog>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

val_list = ['ProductOption','PurchaseOption','Quantity']

for elem in root.findall('.//Variation'):
    sku_tex = []
    sku = ET.Element('Sku')
    elem.append(sku)
    for item in elem.iter():
        if item.tag in val_list and item.text is not None:
            el = item.text.lower().replace(' ','-')+'-'
            sku_tex.append(el)
    sku.text = ''.join(sku_tex).rstrip('-')
    
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree, space='  ')
ET.dump(tree)
```